# Getting an iframe by its id

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want access to an ifram, currently I used following code and it works:

```
window.frames[0].document.body.style.setProperty('direction', 'rtl')
```

But I want get the iframe by its id (`tinymce_ifr`). I tried following but it did not work:

```
document.getElementById('tinymce_ifr').document.body.style.setProperty('direction', 'rtl')
```

What is correct way of doing this work?

Comment: Change `document` to `contentDocument` or `contentWindow.document` to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, it now works: `document.getElementById('tinymce_ifr').contentDocument.body.style.setProperty('direction','ltr');`